# XML, DTD corregir contenido interno del dtd

Tags: xml

Intento hacer que funcione esto sin cambiar el contenido externo, solo cambiando el interno del dtd. Me dice siempre que me falta un "(" en texto o cualquier otro elemento en la linea 8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mensajes [
 <!ELEMENT mensajes (mensaje*)>
 <!ELEMENT mensaje (de, para, hora, texto)>
 <!ELEMENT de (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT para (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT hora (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT texto (((#PCDATA) , strong) | (#PCDATA))>
 <!ELEMENT strong (#PCDATA)>
]>
<mensajes>
 <mensaje>
     <de>Pepe (pepe@example.com)</de>
     <para>Juan (juan@example.com)</para>
     <hora>28/02/2011 17:48:23,61</hora>
     <texto>¿Hola, Juan, qué haces?</texto>
 </mensaje>
 <mensaje>
     <de>Juan (juan@example.com)</de>
     <para>Pepe (pepe@example.com)</para>
     <hora>28/02/2011 17:54:20,87</hora>
     <texto>Aquí, aprendiendo <strong>XML</strong></texto>
 </mensaje>
</mensajes>
```

Este es el error exactamente:

> ```
> (21   A '(' character or an element type is required in the declaration of element type
> "texto").
> ```

Answer (score 0):

La linea 8 debe ser asi para añadir elementos mixtos.
 `<!ELEMENT texto (#PCDATA | strong)*>`